# Where Can I Find Good Contemporary Tabular Data Design Examples

Tags: tables, grid

We are building a reporting/dashboarding application that mixes data visualizations with more traditional gridded tabular type presentation. In our application one can click on a chart, and drill down to a tabular representation of the same data to view the details in an old school grid.

Right now our grids don't really stand out visually.

I'm looking for some examples of visually appealing and easy to read "tables."

Would appreciate some guidance on where to find this...

P.S. below are some examples from our existing app. Looking to improve upon these presentation wise.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show your current view ?

Comment: @keshav - I added some examples

Comment: You might want to see my response and the relevant questions that is asked: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/42674/alternate-row-in-microsoft-modern-ui-metro/56589#56589

Comment: Thanks Michael... this is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

My answer to you would be go through CSS layouts for tables.

Though this site is a bit old it still explains the [different types of table designs](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/08/13/top-10-css-table-designs/) very well. This covers almost all the types of table designs barring what changes you can make to the colours and actions associated with it.

To really make the content stand out you can highlight on hover, or provide comparison with previous period on hover popup that disappear when off focus/ tool tips. Or you can provide side by side representation of current period and previous period columns.

This [site](http://icant.co.uk/csstablegallery/tables/97.php) might also give some ideas on the different table designs available in the market. Also [try this one](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html-table-building-30-beautiful-examples-and-useful-javascripts/)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try looking at [Tableau](http://www.tableausoftware.com/products/online). I've used their desktop app (free trial) and they have some really nice data visualization tools.

You could also check out [extjs](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/#sample-2). They are not as visually compelling out of the box, but they have a lot of nice sorting and filtering tools that you can use.

Another paid option is [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/products/jquery), who makes UI widgets.

Finally, I've personally used [jQuery Data Grids](http://www.datatables.net/), which is simple and themeable and free.